# Other delimiters are used (not & and =) when submitting a form

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get query string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)
>   [How to change how the URL is encoded when a form is submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353539/how-to-change-how-the-url-is-encoded-when-a-form-is-submitted)

I have the site where I have the form and When i push the button's send.
While sending I want to program the submit is form because i want to use the other delimiter `&` and `=`. This is possible?

Now I write one example:

```
www.theuser.com/?Name=IBM&surname=PC
```

With if the function programable while sending

```
www.thepc.com/?Name%24+IBM+%23%+Surname%24+PC
```

Repeat:
 when I sent the parameter, I not want this separator `&` or `=` and I want to use the others.

This Query String is the original for the my project:

```
http://localhost:8100/index2?json_data=demo_title%24+Demo+title+%23+proc1_script%24+script.sh+parameters+%23+proc1_chk_make%24+on+%23+outputp2_value%24++%23+demo_input_description%24+hola+mundo+%23+outputp4_visible%24+on+%23+outputp4_info%24++%23+inputdata1_max_pixels%24+1024000+%23+tag%24++%23+outputp1_id%24+nanana+%23+proc1_src_compresion%24+zip+%23+proc1_chk_cmake%24+off+%23+outputp3_description%24++%23+outputp3_value%24++%23+inputdata1_description%24+input+data+description+%23+inputp2_description%24+bien%3F+%23+inputp3_description%24+funciona+%23+proc1_cmake%24+-D+CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE%3Astring%3DRelease++%23+outputp2_visible%24+on+%23+outputp3_visible%24+on+%23+outputp1_type%24+header+%23+inputp1_type%24+text+%23+demo_params_description%24+va+bien+%23+outputp1_description%24++%23+inputdata1_type%24+image2d+%23+proc1_chk_script%24+off+%23+demo_result_description%24+win%3F+%23+outputp2_id%24+nanfdsvfa+%23+inputp1_description%24+funciona+%23+demo_wait_description%24+boh+%23+outputp4_description%24++%23+inputp2_type%24+integer+%23+inputp2_id%24+papapa+%23+outputp1_value%24++%23+outputp3_id%24+nananartrtrt+%23+inputp3_id%24+pepepe+%23+outputp3_type%24+header+%23+inputp3_visible%24++off+%23+outputp1_visible%24+on+%23+inputdata1_id%24+id_lsd+%23+outputp4_value%24++%23+inputp2_visible%24+on+%23+proc1_source%24+lsd-1.5.zip+%23+inputp3_value%24+si+%23+proc1_make%24+-j4+-C++%23+images_config_file%24+cfgmydemo.cfg+%23+outputp2_type%24+header+%23+proc1_subdir%24+xxx-1.5+%23+proc1_url%24+http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ipol.im%2Fpub%2Falgo%2F...+%23+inputdata1_image_depth%24+1x8i+%23+inputp1_id%24+popopo+%23+inputp1_value%24+si+%23+inputp2_value%24+no+%23+demo_data_filename%24+data_saved.cfg+%23+inputdata1_info%24+info_lsd+%23+outputp3_info%24++%23+inputdata1_image_format%24+.pgm+%23+outputp1_info%24++%23+inputdata1_compress%24+False+%23+inputp1_visible%24+on+%23+proc1_id%24+lsd+%23+outputp4_id%24+nana+%23+outputp2_description%24++%23+outputp4_type%24+header+%23+outputp2_info%24++%23+inputp3_type%24+float+%23+&tag=&inputp4_id=hi&inputp4_type=text&inputp4_description=hello+program&inputp4_value=no&inputp4_info=bol&inputp4_visible=on
```

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript/jQuery?

Comment: More importantly, can I ask ***why*** you would want to use different delimiters?

Comment: @MikeBrant: I don't see another way, do you? It does not seem possible using [pure html](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4)

Comment: Sorry, it's still a little unclear what you mean. Are you saying that you want the form submit to go to the second URL, `www.thepc.com/?Name%24+IBM+%23%+Surname%24+PC`? If not, post the exact URL you're looking for.

Comment: Ehehehhe I use the server with Cherrypy and the program is with pyhton and Mako.
I have the initial data with the variable Mako.
I can add/Edit/Delete the new Data and at the end I collect all the data and write a new file.
I use on the all forms the method GET and i use the querystring.
I can't use the four delimiters (& = %24+ +%23%) because the programming is difficult.

Comment: This is a original Query String http://localhost:8100/index2?json_data=demo_title%24+Demo+title+%23+proc1_script%24+script.sh+parameters+%23+proc1_chk_make%24+on+%23+outputp2_value%24++%23+demo_input_description%24+hola+mundo+%23+outputp4_visible%24+on+%23+outputp4_info%24++%23+inputdata1_max_pixels%24+1024000+%23+tag%24++%23+

Comment: @MikeBrant there is a solution? Change/Edit the delimiters's Query String while Send?

Answer (score 2):

**tldr;** The encoding is "correct"; *however* ..

.. something *incorrectly percent encoded* the full URL.

Only encode the *components* (keys and values), not the full URL or gibberish like this will result.

The `=` and `&` characters are [valid reserved characters](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) in the query portion of a URL and should not be encoded.

Comment: I can not edited the url when I sending the parameter?

Comment: @begginnerofall Sure you can - just make sure to encode it *correctly*, which might be "don't encode it twice" or "encode it by component". Provided details of *how* this URL was construct and *how* it is used in the post would be beneficial.